# Android: Get contact name using phone number

Tags: java, android, contacts

I am trying to access contact but keeps getting null pointer error.

`NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method ' 
android.content.ContentResolver android.content.Context.getContentResolver()' on a null object reference`

**Code**

```
 public static String getContactName(Context context, String phoneNumber) {
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String contactName = null;
    String contactNumber = "";
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }

    if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }

    return contactNumber.equals("") ? phoneNumber : contactName;
}
```

Here is how I use it

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {

String contactName;
String phoneNumber;
Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

    //Set caller phone
    String number = getIntent().getStringExtra(
            TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

   contactName = getContactName(context, number);
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    text.setText(contactName);

}
```

Is it possible to call BroadcastReceiver in an activity?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How have you called your getContactName. Your context is null it seems and hence the error. Can you add your method call code from where you have called this method in your post

Comment: your context is null can you show from where you are calling method

Comment: Ok. I will add it

Comment: I have updated the calling method. Is it possible to call BroadcastReceiver in an activity? I am guessing that is why it is returning null?

Comment: @Olalekan check my answer.

Comment: @Olalekan I never get the contact name, it always returns the contact number. Can you update this with the permissions you have enabled? and also the final code for how you got the contact Name showing

Comment: For anyone who comes to view this in the future, check update for working return statement. The condition `contactNumber.equals("") ` is always true and not appropriate in the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't initialize the value `context` in your activity, and you are calling from activity so you can call like this,

```
contactName = getContactName(this, number);
```

or you can set the context value and call like this,

```
context = this;
contactName = getContactName(context, number);
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try it, I will give feedback.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void ContactList(){
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME}, selection, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");


        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {

            String contactNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            String contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

            }
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        cursor = null;

      }
```